# Angular ng-repeat with ng-src

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio

My project is in visual studio and Im trying to use ng-src to bind the "ImageLocation" to it.

```
<body ng-app="TravelApp" ng-controller="Controller" class="">

<div class="centering-container">
    <div class="material-container">
        <div class="padding-25">
            <form class="form" role="search" method="get">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control"     placeholder="Search" ng-model="searchTerm">
                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
            <div style="padding-top:25px;">
                <button ng-click="getData()" type="button" class="material-button ">Lets Go!</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


</div>
<div class="container-fluid" id="package-container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4" ng-repeat="p in packageList | filter : searchTerm">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img ng-src="{{p.packageImageLocation}}" alt="PackageImage">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h3>{{p.packageTitle}}</h3>
                    <p>{{p.packageLocation}}</p>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>


</div>
```

The images wont load but when i inspect the page in chrome the root is correct.

PackageImageLocation = "~/images/sydney-opera-house-night.jpeg"

the above is the field.

I think I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4" ng-repeat="p in packageList">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img ng-src="{{p.packageImageLocation}}" alt="PackageImage">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>{{p.packageTitle}}</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/d297geon/)**

Comment: It was already in a controller. I just hadn't added it to the code in the question.